# Zuul ServiceId route is not working on CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, pcfdev

I am unable to call to microservices using zuul serviceId .

getting below error on cloudfoundry for zuul gateway.

"2024-01-31 11:52:29.285 ERROR 496 --- [      Thread-14] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_XYZ-ZUUL/XYZ-zuul:2ecdce4ee6ba542f777055b83ec2ac14 - de-registration failedCannot execute request on any known server "

Below are the routes details on bootstrap-system.yml file
#Zuul gateway routes
zuul:
debug.request: true
ignoreSecurityHeaders: false
sensitiveHeaders: Content-Security-Policy, X-Content-Security-Policy, X-WebKit-CSP
routes:
# these two routes handled by zuul gateway itself; see controller classes
gatewayLogout:
path: /gatewaylogout
url: "forward:"
userExperience:
path: /useraccesscheck
url: "forward:"
# sample route for zuulHost/xps/api to backend api on localhost
actuator:
path: /actuator/**
url: "forward:/actuator"
XYZ-api:
path: /abc/XYZ/api/**
serviceId: XYZ-API
XYZ-ui:
path: /abc/XYZ/**
url: http://XYZ-ui.apps.system.pcf.test.com/abc/XYZ/

This serviceId: XYZ-API ( Eureka Service registry )  is used to run our services in multiple instance

Instead of serviceId if I replaced  with url it's working fine but it will run only single instance

```
 XYZ-api:
  path: /abc/XYZ/api/**
  url: https://XYZ-api.apps.system.pcf.test.com/
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.